# Where is the Python gen_py folder located?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, win32com

I'm trying to save an Excel spreadsheet into a PDF file using Win32 in Python.

The code is here:

```
infile='c:/Infile.xlsx'
wb=client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
ws=wb.Workbooks.Open(filename)
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,'c:\\OutputFile.pdf')
wb.Quit()
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes I get the following error: `module win32com.gen_py has no attribute 'CLSIDToPackageMap'`

So apparently the answer can be found in this github [article](https://gist.github.com/rdapaz/63590adb94a46039ca4a10994dff9dbe):

So apply it here:

```
try:
    wb=win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
except AttributeError:
    f_loc=r'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py'
    for f in Path(f_loc):
        Path.unlink(f)
    Path.rmdir(f_loc)
    wb=win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "H:\toc2.py", line 90, in <module>
        for f in Path(f_loc):
    
    TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable
```

I searched my Windows 10 enterprise, and did not find any folder called `gen_py`, only a Python file called `gen.py` in `C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py`.

Why don't I have the folder? I'm using Python 3.7.6 on Windows 10 Enterprise, and Spyder 4.0.1.

Thank you.